# Snakemake report: visualize results with vega

Tags: report, snakemake, vega

I notice that `vega` is used by snakemake report to generate workflow summaries such as runtime statistics, for example [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_downloads/b10d83889c3905e7b7557a62144a51ca/report.html).

Is it possible for me to also generate `vega` reports for results of my own?

Answer (score 0):

Once your snakemake workflow has completed successfully, you can generate a report with:

```
snakemake --report report.html
```

Read more about the reports feature here: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/reporting.html